# Saving image from app / camera

Tags: java, android

I have this code in MainActivity: 
onCreate() :

```
mtestImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImage);
mtestImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data):

```
if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
          if (reqCode == 1) {
             mtestImage.setImageURI(data.getData());
          }
      }
```

It works and ImageView shows me the picture that I opened, but if I restart Activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

The ImageView is restore default picture. How Can I save image that I took to work with it in future? (I'm trying to change BG of DrawerMenu with new pictures, that user can choose). 
I founud some code in internet, but I'm not sure how I can combine it with my code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException
    {
        String timeSnap = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeSnap + " ";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        return image;
    }
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this code.


private Uri getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".camerapics");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        Uri uri = null;
        if (mediaFile != null) {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

        }
        return uri;
    }


    mtestImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImage);
mtestImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFile();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });


        public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data)
{
if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
          if (reqCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri));
            mtestImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

setUsername(this,fileUri.getPath());

```
          }
      }
      }
```